# Descifrar este código de wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Saludos amigos, estoy haciendo una aplicación para insertar entradas a un `Wordpress` desde una plataforma externa, ya lo he logrado todo pero estoy teniendo problemas con los `thumbnails` de la imagen destacada, ya la copio en el directorio de `Wordpress` en la carpeta */uploads/año/mes* y todo bien.

El problema es que `Wordpress` genera automáticamente unos `thumbnails` de dicha imagen y registra en la tabla `wp_postmeta` un registro llamado `[_wp_attachment_metadata]` y no tengo ni idea como hacer ese código para las entradas no se como se interpreta el código se los dejo a ver si me pueden ayudar a crear una función que genere ese código.

> a:5{s:5:"width";i:400;s:6:"height";i:300;s:4:"file";s:17:"2017/02/4.png";s:5:"sizes";a:2:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:17:"4-150x150.png";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:9:"image/png";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:17:"4-300x225.png";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:225;s:9:"mime-type";s:9:"image/png";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:12:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"0";s:8:"keywords";a:0:{}}}

Answer (score 0):

Oh gracias, ya conseguí respuestas investigando y probando, resulta que logre hacer unserialize a el string y logre analizarlo me daba errores porque cuando modificaba algún valor tenía que modificar también los "s:xx" que no era mas que el strlen del valor dejo una imagen donde desglosa la imágen y me sirvió para interpretar esa información use la función unserialize de PHP.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]